# Oracle: Updates only allowed with comment

Tags: oracle, triggers, comments, procedure

The question is maybe a little strange. But I am looking for a way that updates on a table are only allowed when the user gives a comment. The comments should be saved in a second audit-table when updating the normal table.
I think there is no way in oracle how the user can give a comment when executing "update table set...". 
 
So i create my own procedure, where a user can pass the statement and the comment as parameters. Updates without this procedure are prevented by a trigger.

```
create or replace
    PROCEDURE Update_Table(stmt varchar2, comment varchar2) AS 
    BEGIN
        Insert into audit_table values(stmt, comment);
        Execute immediate stmt;
END Update_Table;
```

I am not really happy with this solution. So maybe there is solution much simpler.

Comment: What about a view that includes a "comment" column and has an instead of trigger that does the update on the main table and inserts the comment into the audit table. Then you can revoke update privilege on the table and all updates must go through the view. Don't know if such a trigger is possible though.

Comment: ok, but i also need a procedure like above, or?

Comment: No procedure, only the trigger.

Answer (score 5):

The standard approach would be to prevent users from issuing `UPDATE` statements against the base table.  Normally, you would revoke `UPDATE` privileges and then create a stored procedure (presumably in a package along with procedures to do other sorts of DML operations like `INSERT` on that table) that you grant the users the privileges to use.  Your users would then call the stored procedure, passing in a comment, and the stored procedure would implement whatever validation is necessary before actually updating the table.

If for some reason you really do need to give users the ability to issue explicit `UPDATE` statements, can you require that they call a stored procedure before issuing the `UPDATE` statement?  If so, you could create a package with a package-level variable for the comment and a procedure to set the comment and then create a trigger on the table that reads the data from this package-level variable, throws an exception if it is not set, and does whatever logging you need.

Another option would be to actually add the `comment` column to the table itself to store the comment for the last modification and then create a statement-level trigger that writes the comment to a separate table and a constraint on the table that forces the `comment` to be set.

You could also, as @a_horse_with_no_name suggests, revoke access to the table, create a view that includes the `comment` column, and then write an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger that checks whether the statement is setting the `comment` column to an appropriate value and then issues the appropriate DML against the base tables.